# Can I configure a kind of trigger isolation with Quartz?

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler

My application is split into 2 web applications running in the same container sharing one db.

The first war does only background processing and the other is for the client GUI + some background stuffs.

The application with the client GUI allows the user to configure the scheduling of some tasks that will be executed by the "background application". Basically it configures the Quartz jobs and triggers.

I'd like that the scheduler of the background application handles only the jobs of a certain group (bg-jobs), and that the other scheduler handles the other group (fg-jobs).

Is it possible to configure this kind of isolation with quartz?

Note: I'd like to keep it simple and if I can avoid to use Quartz Where which seems to be liek a hammer to sledge this probably overkill for my need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and quickest way is to create a separate load of tables for each application. So have one set of quartz tables prefixed with "bg-" and another prefixed with "fg-". Then just change your schedulers configs to point at the appropriate tables. I know it might be a little awkward but you did say you wanted to keep it simple :).

Comment: But how can I configure both scheduler from one application?

Comment: How are you configuring the two schedulers? Spring xml?

Comment: yes, in fact I am thinking of creating 2 isolated scheduler and managing with JMX

Comment: in spring when you config a SchedulerFactoryBean you have to set a property called org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix, set this differently for each instance. e.g. "bg-", "fg-"